# Why does this SQL code returns true when both operands operated by operator OR are False?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I run the following SQL for Table 'Orders' as shown below :

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE EmployeeID = 99 OR "TEST" ;
OrderID CustomerID EmployeeID OrderDate ShipperID 
10248     90          5       7/4/1996    3  
10249     81          6       7/5/1996    1
```

I was in a process of studying and understanding SQL Injections  , hence i had earlier tried the following , which as expected did return TRUE and hence displays the complete table 'Orders' , but in the above case when run it still shows the complete table , why ? even though the net result is a FALSE as in
  EmployeeID = 99 OR "TEST"
there is no value in column 'EmployeeID' which equals 99 , and all values are numeric .

Comment: You probably wanted this query: `SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE EmployeeID = 99 OR EmployeeID  = "TEST"`

Comment: `EmployeeID = 99 OR "TEST"` = `(EmployeeID = 99) OR "TEST"`

Comment: Your string delimiters are wrong, does this even execute?

Comment: can not reproduce. Error:`An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'test'.: select * from test where id=99 or 'test'` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/50017/3

Comment: @Cthulhu I think that answers my query , the comparison (EmployeeID = 99) OR "TEST" works as  0 OR 1  , and hence returns true executing the rest. Thanx

Comment: And if your id column is actually a `varchar` or similar just containing numeric data you get a different error:`An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'test'.: select * from test where id=99 or 'test'`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cd666/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because "TEST" is always true.

Remember:

```
false OR false => false
false OR true => true
true OR false => true
true OR true => true
```

In your case it does not matter if EmployeeID = 99 is true or not...

By the way: This is how injections work.

Answer (score 2):

because the boolean value of "TEST" is always true.  You need to try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE EmployeeID = 99 OR EmployeeID =  'TEST' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT <fill in column list here, never use select * in production code> FROM Orders WHERE (EmployeeID = 99 OR  EmployeeID = "TEST" );
```

Comment: It is not just performance is it also maintainability and it is also performance because anytime you use an inner join you are returning unneeded information that is using up resources. It is a sql antipattern.

Answer (score 1):

So you want all records if there is no `EmployeeId=99`? Then you just have to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Orders o1 WHERE o1.EmployeeID = 99)
OR EmployeeID = 99
```

You don't need to be afraid that this simple sub-query is executed more than once in SQL-Server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you actually mean

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE (EmployeeID = 99) OR (EmployeeID = "TEST");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
WHERE (EmployeeID = 99 OR EmployeeID = "TEST")
```

The result will appear in OR because it only needs one of the two is true. For the case of AND, the two need to be true at the same time!

This test is weird because "TEST" is string, and EmployeeID is numeric.

Answer (score 0):

There is still no accepted answer so I am going to explain what everyone is saying.
Your query is actually interpreted as this:

`SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE EmployeeID = 99 OR "TEST" = "TEST" ;`

thus your second condition is always true.